# Converting a modified JSON to CSV using python

Tags: python, json, csv

I know this question has been asked before, but never with the following caveats:

- I'm a complete python n00b. Also a JSON noob.
- The JSON file / string is not the same as those seen in json2csv examples.
- The CSV file output is supposed to have standard columns.

Due to point number 1, I'm not aware of most terminologies and technologies used for this. So please bear with me.

Point number 2: Here's a single line of the *supposed* JSON file:

```
"id":"123456","about":"YESH","can_post":true,"category":"Community","checkins":0,"description":"OLE!","has_added_app":false,"is_community_page":false,"is_published":true,"likes":48,"link":"www.fake.com","name":"Test Name","parking":{"lot":0,"street":0,"valet":0},"talking_about_count":0,"website":"www.fake.com/blog","were_here_count":0^
```

Weird, I know - it lacks braces and brackets and stuff. Which is why I'm convinced posted solutions won't work.

I'm not sure what the 0^ at the end of the line is, but I see it at the end of every line. I'm assuming the 0 is the value for "were_here_count" while the ^ is a... line terminator? EDIT: Apparently, I can just disregard it.

Of note is that the value of "parking" appears to be yet another array - I'm fine with just displaying it as is (minus the double quotes).

Point number 3: Here's the columns of the supposed CSV file output. This is the complete column set - the JSON file won't always have them all.

```
ID STRING,
ABOUT STRING,
ATTIRE STRING,
BAND_MEMBERS STRING,
BEST_PAGE STRING,
BIRTHDAY STRING,
BOOKING_AGENT STRING,
CAN_POST STRING,
CATEGORY STRING,
CATEGORY_LIST STRING,
CHECKINS STRING,
COMPANY_OVERVIEW STRING,
COVER STRING,
CONTEXT STRING,
CURRENT_LOCATION STRING,
DESCRIPTION STRING,
DIRECTED_BY STRING,
FOUNDED STRING,
GENERAL_INFO STRING,
GENERAL_MANAGER STRING,
GLOBAL_BRAND_PARENT_PAGE STRING,
HOMETOWN STRING,
HOURS STRING,
IS_PERMANENTLY_CLOSED STRING,
IS_PUBLISHED STRING,
IS_UNCLAIMED STRING,
LIKES STRING,
LINK STRING,
LOCATION STRING,
MISSION STRING,
NAME STRING,
PARKING STRING,
PHONE STRING,
PRESS_CONTACT STRING,
PRICE_RANGE STRING,
PRODUCTS STRING,
RESTAURANT_SERVICES STRING,
RESTAURANT_SPECIALTIES STRING,
TALKING_ABOUT_COUNT  STRING,
USERNAME STRING,
WEBSITE STRING,
WERE_HERE_COUNT STRING
```

Here's my code so far:

```
import os

num = '1'
inPath = "./fb-data_input/"
outPath = "./fb-data_output/"
#Get list of Files, put them in filenameList array
fileNameList = os.listdir(path)
#Process per file in 
for item in fileNameList:
    print("Processing: " + item)
    fb_inputFile = open(inPath + item, "rb").read().split("\n")
    fb_outputFile = open(outPath + "fbdata-IAB-output" + num, "wb")
    num++
    jsonString = fb_inputFile.split("\",\"")
    jsonField = jsonString[0]
    jsonValue = jsonString[1]
    jsonHash[?] = [?,?]
    #Do Code stuff here
```

Up until the for loop, it just loads the json file names into an array, and then processes it one by one.

Here's my logic for the rest of the code:

- Split the json string by something. Perhaps the "," so that other commas won't get split.
- Store it into a hashmap / 2D array (dynamic?)
- Trim away the JSON fields and the first and/or last double quotes.
- Add the resulting output to another hashmap, with those set columns, putting in null in a column that the JSON file does not have.

And then I output the result to a CSV.

It sounds logical in my head, but I'm pretty sure there's something I missed. And of course, I have a hard time putting it in code.

Can I have some help on this? Thanks.

P.S.

Additional information:

- OS: Mac OSX
- Target platform OS: Ubuntu of some sort

Comment: Do the lines of the JSON files correspond to a single data record?

Comment: How does `"parking":{"lot":0,"street":0,"valet":0}` map to the `PARKING` column of the CSV?

Comment: And what does the `^` character at the end of the line signify?

Comment: You don't have a json string.

Comment: @JamieCockburn, yes, that's a single line. As for the ^, it's perhaps a next line delimited left over from the last process. As for PARKING, I'm told it can be left as is (minus the ").

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, that's what I thought too, but it's closer to a JSON string than anything, and I was hoping some of those existing converters could be modified, or at least, the string itself be modified to be similar to JSON.

Comment: Why? You don't need to modify it to json because it doesn't represent an object. Your task is to read the string, split it up at the comma, figure out the key and value pairs, fill in any missing columns and then write it back out. For this, json would not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full solution, based on your original code:

```
import os
import json
from csv import DictWriter
import codecs

def get_columns():
    columns = []
    with open("columns.txt") as f:
        columns = [line.split()[0] for line in f if line.strip()]
    return columns

if __name__ == "__main__":
    in_path = "./fb-data_input/"
    out_path = "./fb-data_output/"
    columns = get_columns()
    bad_keys = ("has_added_app", "is_community_page")
    for filename in os.listdir(in_path):
        json_filename = os.path.join(in_path, filename)
        csv_filename = os.path.join(out_path, "%s.csv" % (os.path.basename(filename)))
        with open(json_filename) as f, open(csv_filename, "wb") as csv_file:
            csv_file.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
            csv = DictWriter(csv_file, columns)
            csv.writeheader()
            for line_number, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
                try:
                    data = json.loads("{%s}" % (line.strip().strip('^')))
                    # fix parking column
                    if "parking" in data:
                        data['parking'] = ", ".join("%s: %s" % (k, str(v)) for k, v in data['parking'].items())
                    data = {k.upper(): unicode(v).encode('utf8') for k, v in data.items() if k not in bad_keys}
                except Exception, e:
                    import traceback
                    traceback.print_exc()
                    data = {columns[0]: "Error on line %s of %s: %s" % (line_number, json_filename, e)}
                csv.writerow(data)
```

**Edited**: Full unicode support plus extended error information.

Comment: What's with the mix of camelCase and underscores for variable names?

Comment: @Eli Ha! Hadn't noticed! The camelCase ones are copied from the OP, the underscore ones are me.  Better? :)

Comment: Much better. Pep8 FTW! :)

Comment: I'm getting a `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019'`. I'm assuming this has something to do with the content of the "json" strings. According to Google, I should set `unicodeData.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` but I'm not sure where to put that nor how it works.

Comment: if you are getting that error, it means that your input data has non-[ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters in it.  Examples are non-latin characters, certain currency or punctuation symbols, and anything else not in the ASCII table. `encode('ascii', 'ignore')` will work, but it will skip any such character. So for example the Norwegian word "bjørn" (bear) would become "bjrn", obviously not what you want to happen.  The answer is to use an encoding that does support such characters, or to manually work out a good mapping (ø for o). I will update my answer to encode the data in `UTF-8`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Yeah, I've seen some Chinese characters in there, sorry for failing to mention that earlier. Now I'm getting `'bool' object has no attribute 'encode'` on the last line.

Comment: Another edit.  The JSON decoding will take `"can_post":true` for example and create a proper python `bool` object.  `.encode(...)` only works on strings. This time I'm explicitly converting all the values to a string before doing encoding with `str(v).encode(...)`. (I also moved the encoding, because it didn't make sense to go through the dictionary twice like that.)

Comment: Getting a different error this time: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`. Something to do with `data['PARKING'] = ", ".join("%s: %s" % (k, str(v)) for k, v in data['PARKING'].items())`

Comment: @zack_falcon sorry, hadn't actually tested my edits. Doing them on my phone! Try that out for size.

Comment: On the phone? Wow. My apologies for bothering you, but it's still giving me a `ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019`, but this time, on line: `data = dict(((k.upper(), str(v).encode('utf8')) for k, v in data.items() if k not in bad_keys))`

Comment: Can you post the data that is breaking it and your `columns.txt`? Maybe put it on pastebin or something?

Comment: Here's the link for the columns.txt, though it's more or less exactly the same as above: http://pastebin.com/g06Nq1jD. Now as for the data, it's very large, there's more than one file, and I'm not sure I'm allowed to post it - school stuff and all. I'm very sorry about that. Is there anything else I can provide?

Comment: @zack_falcon Okay!  Finally tested it on my PC, this final version will support all unicode characters, and gives you nice error messages for other problem right in the generated CSV (try it out be corrupting a line in your JSON file).

Answer (score 1):

So, first off, your string is valid json if you just add curly braces around it. You can then deserialize with Python's [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library. Setup your csv columns as a dictionary with each of them pointing to whatever you want as a default value (None? ""? you're choice). Once you've deserialized the json to a dict, just loop through each key there and fill in the csv_columns dict as appropriate. Then just use Python's csv module to write it out:

```
import json
import csv
string = '"id":"123456","about":"YESH","can_post":true,"category":"Community","checkins":0,"description":"OLE!","has_added_app":false,"is_community_page":false,"is_published":true,"likes":48,"link":"www.fake.com","name":"Test Name","parking":{"lot":0,"street":0,"valet":0},"talking_about_count":0,"website":"www.fake.com/blog","were_here_count":0^'
string = '{%s}' % string[:-1]
json_dict = json.loads(string)
#make 'parking' a string. I'm assuming that's your only hash.
json_dict['parking'] = json.dumps(json_dict['parking'])
csv_cols_list = ['a','b','c'] #put your actual csv columns here
csv_cols = {col: '' for col in csv_cols_list}
for k, v in json_dict.iterkeys():
    if k in csv_cols:
        csv_cols[k] = v
#now just write to csv using Python's csv library
```

**Note:** this is a general answer that assumes that your "json" will be valid key/value pairs. Your "parking" key is a special case you'll need to deal with somehow. I left it as is because I don't know what you want with it. I'm also assuming the '^' at the end of your string was a typo.

**[EDIT]** Changed to account for `parking` and the '^' at the end. **[/EDIT]**

Either way, the general idea here is what you want.

Comment: I've edited the question since posting it up, sorry for the lack of details early on. The "Parking" key can be left as is - a string.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is your input is not JSON. Its just a string that is delimited, where the column and value is quoted.

Here is a solution that would work:

```
import csv

columns = ['ID', 'ABOUT', ... ]

with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as f, open('output_file.txt', 'w') as o:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(columns)
    for row in reader:
       data = {k.upper():v for k,v in row.split(':', 1)}
       row = [data.get(v, '') for v in columns]
       writer.writerow(row)
```

In this loop, for each line we read from the input file, a dictionary is created. The key is the first value from the `'foo:bar'` pair, and we convert it to upper case.

Next, for each column, we try to fetch a value from this dictionary in the order that the columns are written out. If a value for the column doesn't exist, a blank  `''` is returned.  These values are collected in a list *`row`*.  This makes sure no matter how many columns are missing, we write an equal number of columns to the output.

Comment: This would break on his `parking` key.

Comment: No, it won't. The value is a single string, and in the output there is only one column for "parking". Keep in mind the input is not valid JSON, its just a string.

Comment: You are splitting the row on ":". That will get you keys with brackets in them for parking, like '{"lot":0'. There's no way that's what OP wants.